# CertSrv is requesting certificates with FQDN but not with Server IP

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, ip-address, fqdn

We have webserver where certificate Authority webenrollment role installed and it is pointing to Issuing CA

When ever we try `htps://webservername/certsrv` then I can able to request certificates

but when I try `htps://webserver<Ip Address>/certsrv` then in the last step while requesting certificate the following error appears... can anyone help to resolve this

[image]

Comment: and what details say?

Comment: It is an RPC error... but all ports firewalls are enabled any to any so there is no network blockage